# biblatex-apa7 full first names in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, apa-style

Usually, `biblatex-apa` gives authors' names in the bibliography as

> Lastname, F. (2000). *Booktitle*. Publisher.

Unfortunately, my professor explicitly wants it to be written as:

> Lastname, Firstname I. (2000). *Booktitle*. Publisher.

My code looks a little something like this:

```
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,
    pagesize=auto
    12pt,
    ngerman,
    usegeometry,
    oneside,
    headinclude=false,
    footinclude=true,
    BCOR=0mm,
    DIV=calc,
    parskip=onehalf,
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex} %This should render as APA7, the current version of the APA guidline
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Test.bib}
@book{Lastname2000,
  author = {given={Firstname Initial}}, family=Lastname},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  title = {Booktitle},
  year = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{Test.bib}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite[S.~222]{Lastname2000}. Quod equitur...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I've already read the answer provided at [biblatex-apa: full first names in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191076/biblatex-apa-full-first-names-in-the-bibliography) , but this doesn't work for the current version of `biblatex-apa` (I assume?), at least I'm getting nothing but errors from this solution.

Comment: Because it seems, that the professor does not want APA7, how about using `biblatex-apa6` to try the code from the answer to the linked question …

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not doing anything, even after recompiling several times. Also, the professor wants us to use APA 7th edition, just the first names of the authors fully written out, but nothing else changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to mess with the internal implementation of the name formatting macros. The following definition is based on (and was tested with) `biblatex-apa` v9.16 (2022/06/22).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{name:apa:family-given}[5]{%
  \togglefalse{apablx@wantcomma}%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#4#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#4#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{%
       \mkbibnameprefix{#4}\isdot%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\toggletrue{apablx@wantcomma}%
                      \revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}%
     \ifdefvoid{#5}{}{\toggletrue{apablx@wantcomma}%
                      \addcomma\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#5}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\toggletrue{apablx@wantcomma}%
                      \bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{%
       \toggletrue{apablx@wantcomma}%
       \bibnamedelimc\mkbibnameprefix{#4}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \ifdefvoid{#5}{}{\toggletrue{apablx@wantcomma}%
                      \addcomma\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#5}\isdot}}%
  \let\bibstring\bibcplstring
  \usebibmacro{role}{\addspace}{\mkbibparens}%
  \hasitemannotation[\currentname][username]
    {\addspace\mkbibbrackets{\getitemannotation[\currentname][username]}}
    {}%
  \apablx@ifrevnameappcomma
    {\addcomma}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:apa:given-family}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#4#1#5}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#4#1#5}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#4}\isdot
    \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot%
  \ifdefvoid{#5}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#5}\isdot}%
  \let\bibstring\bibcpsstring
  \usebibmacro{role}{\addcomma\space}{\@firstofone}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Lastname2000,
  author    = {Firstname Initial Lastname},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  title     = {Booktitle},
  year      = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite[222]{Lastname2000}. Quod equitur...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lastname, Firstname Initial. (2000). Booktitle. Publisher.]

You won't need the extended name format for this. (And the example entry had a bracing error, so I went back to the usual name input format.)

Comment: The approach is still the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477986/35864. But the definitions and names of relevant macros have changed over time.